# Does JSON have a declared index base?

Tags: json, standards

I've read through both the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) and [JSON.org](http://json.org) and couldn't see a reference to whether array indexes were 0-based or 1-based. Being originally 'discovered' in JS, does everyone just assume it is 0-based?

For example:

```
{ 
  "selectedItem": 1,
  "Items": ["boots", "gloves", "hat"]
}
```

Is the selected item "boots" or "gloves"?

If this is the case (assumed 0-based), isn't this assumption potentially troublesome, particular if JSON support is implemented in languages that by default use 1-based indexes?

Comment: **J**ava**S**cript**O**bject**N**otation. Js is zero based. Where is the confusion?

Comment: When something is implemented in other languages, generally specifications (see: RFC-4627) should be unambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think *array index* is a concept covered by JSON at all. A JSON array is just an ordered set written in a particular fashion:

> An *array* is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with `[` (left bracket) and ends with `]` (right bracket). Values are separated by `,` (comma).

And that's all there is to it. Indexing questions are left to the end-points, the first element could be index 0, 1, -10, or `"pancakes"` and it wouldn't make any difference at all to JSON as long as the indexes matched the order of the elements in the array.

Back to specifics. Whether `"selectedItem": 1` refers to `"boots"` or `"gloves"` is up to the JSON producer.

Comment: So, in short, the producer would have to inform consumers what index reference system they are using? (be it, 1..2.., 0..1.. or pancakes...shortcakes...?)

Comment: @DanMcGrath: Correct. JSON is a data transport mechanism, the semantics of that transported data is someone else's problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, and it doesn't need one. There's no such thing as an array index in JSON. That `selectedItem` field is a simple integer. If it holds some reference to the other field, that's in the application domain, not the data notation.

JSON provides no means for referencing an element of an array, so the base index number is irrelevant.